# How to speed up Selenium/Junit test execution by avoiding the registry settings

Tags: java, internet-explorer, junit, continuous-integration, jenkins

we have 500+ test cases for our application. Test cases are running for 4 to 6 hours based on the CPU and RAM overhead.

For each test case Selenium will start and stop the IE. IE takes the backup of the registry for each test case. I am seeing the following statements for each test case and

```
14:43:38,312 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager] Backing up registry settings...
14:43:40,234 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager] Modifying registry settings...
```

There is 2 minutes time difference between above two statements.

Can we bypass the backup of the registry and run the test cases. In this way my test cases will finish less than 20min to current build.

Answer (score 1):

This [thread](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/selenium-reuse-existing-browser-session-instead-of-opening-new-windows) shows how to reuse a Firefox session.  I haven't tried it, but I imagine there is an equivalent for Internet Explorer.  You could also use [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) to speed up the duration.